# Unable to open mozila firefox 48.2 using selenium webdriver 2.45.0

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

Error is

> Unable to open mozila firefox 48.2 using selenium webdriver 2.45.0

This is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class OpenBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        Driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        }

}
```

Comment: You should upgrade your selenium version as well

Comment: Download Firefox from this link https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/win64-EME-free/en-GB/Firefox%20Setup%2046.0.1.exe and then try again

Answer (score 0):

Firefox versions after 47 are not compatible with Selenium versions lower than 2.53 (this included)
So you need to download selenium3 beta and configure the geckodriver to run firefox (as you will do for driver with chromedriver. 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: Thanks you. Now i got it.